# Query builded with division

Tags: mysql, cakephp-3.0

I need to send an email every 48 hours from a datetime field. 
My sql query is:

```
select * from leads where datediff(NOW(),`level7_email_sent`)%2 = 0
```

How I do it with CakePHP query builder? My problem is division.

Whats I done is:

```php
        $leads = $this->Leads->find();
            //->contain([])
        $leads->where(function (QueryExpression $exp, Query $q) {
                $datediff = $q->func()->dateDiff([
                    'NOW()' => 'literal',
                    'level7_email_sent' => 'identifier'
                ]);
                return $exp->eq('engagement_level',7)->eq($datediff,7);
            });
```

I don't know how to do the division, thanks.

Comment: You have 2 problems actually! A `%` symbol is not a division symbol

Comment: And the only thing that would ever `=0` when divided by 2 would be 2

Comment: english is not my main language, maybe there is another term to use, using % you get a reminder of a division

Comment: `  $leads = $this->Leads->find();
            //->contain([])
        $leads->where(function (QueryExpression $exp, Query $q) {
                $datediff = $q->func()->dateDiff([
                    'NOW()' => 'literal',
                    'level7_email_sent' => 'identifier'
                ]);
                return $exp->eq('engagement_level',7)->eq($datediff,0);
            });`
Equal 7 was an error, must be 0

Comment: Hint: A `%` stands for Modulo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved using HAVING

```
    $leads = $this->Leads->find();
    //->contain([])
    $datediff = $leads->func()->dateDiff([
        'NOW()' => 'literal',
        'level8_email_sent' => 'identifier'
    ]);
    $leads->select(['dateDiff'=>$datediff])
        ->enableAutoFields(true)
        ->where(['engagement_level'=>7])
        ->having(['MOD(`dateDiff`,2)'=>0]);
```